# What does __VA_ARGS__ in a macro mean?

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-macros, variadic-functions

```
/* Debugging */
#ifdef DEBUG_THRU_UART0
#   define DEBUG(...)  printString (__VA_ARGS__)
#else
void dummyFunc(void);
#   define DEBUG(...)  dummyFunc()   
#endif
```

I've seen this notation in different headers of C programming, I basically understood it's passing arguments, but I didn't understand what this "three dots notation" is called?

Can someone explain it with example or provide links also about VA Args?

Answer (score 63):

It's a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) macro. It means you can call it with any number of arguments. The three `...` is similar to the same construct used in a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) in C

That means you can use the macro like this

```
DEBUG("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Or with any number of arguments.

The __VA_ARGS__ refers back again to the variable arguments in the macro itself.

```
#define DEBUG(...)  printString (__VA_ARGS__)
               ^                     ^
               +-----<-refers to ----+
```

So  `DEBUG("foo", "bar", "baz");` would be replaced with `printString ("foo", "bar", "baz")`

Answer (score 19):

The dots are called, together with the `__VA_ARGS__`, variadic macros

> When the macro is invoked, **all the tokens in its argument list**  [...], including any commas,
> **become the variable argument**. This sequence of tokens replaces the
> identifier `__VA_ARGS__` in the macro body wherever it appears.

[source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), bold emphasis of mine.

A sample of usage:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_THRU_UART0
#   define DEBUG(...)  printString (__VA_ARGS__)
#else
void dummyFunc(void);
#   define DEBUG(...)  dummyFunc()   
#endif
DEBUG(1,2,3); //calls printString(1,2,3) or dummyFunc() depending on
              //-DDEBUG_THRU_UART0 compiler define was given or not, when compiling.
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically... it means that it converts the function into multiple arguments and you have the ability to add multiple arguments to your function.
Of course, `__va_args__` is used so that if you `#define` a variable or function, you can convert it into several arguments with...
The point is that you should also use the `va_list` and `va_start` functions in addition to this mode that exists in `#define`.

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int, ...);

int main(void) {
    printf("Sum of 10, 20 and 30 = %d\n", sum(3, 10, 20, 30) );
    printf("Sum of 4, 20, 25 and 30 = %d\n", sum(4, 4, 20, 25, 30) );

    return 0;
}

int sum(int num_args, ...) {
    int val = 0;
    va_list ap;
    int i;

    va_start(ap, num_args);
    for(i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
       val += va_arg(ap, int);
    }
    va_end(ap);
 
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Variadic macros (`__VA_ARGS__`) and variadic functions are not related at all.

Comment: Look at this link:
https://snai.pe/posts/varargs

Comment: A good read and it certainly relates variadic macros to variadic functions, but it presents variadic macros only as a solution to improve variadic functions. You should not normally go from variadic macros to functions.