# what does "..." do as a function argument in C?

Tags: c, stdio

I have been wondering how C's printf function worked, so I decided to look at gcc's stdio.h for the definition. To my surprise, the printf function in gcc is defined with the arguments "const char*, . . . ". I tried doing this for myself, in a simple program that I made.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Print(const char *text, ...) {

    printf("%s\n", text);
}

int main() {
    Print("Hello, World!", "a");
}
```

I can pass however many arguments I want into it, even though those arguments won't have any future access point. I am wondering more about this, and I wish to know if anybody has more information.

Comment: [C Variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic). Most C reference texts will include a section on how they work, and how the variadic arguments list macros are used in their conjunction.

Comment: They are called [variadic functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) and their arguments can be handled using the `va_*` functions.

Comment: Also related: [Technically, how do variadic functions work? How does printf work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104628/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ISO C defines a syntax for declaring a function to take a variable number or type of arguments.
Using `...` notation with stdarg.h you can implement variadic funtion: functions that accept an unlimited number of argument. Its usage is explained in Gnu library [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html).

You can go through the parameters using **va_args** from stdarg.h. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html) is good tutorial to start with.

You can also implement variadic macros `SOME_MACRO(...)`. For that you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053959/what-does-va-args-in-a-macro-mean).